# Google Vision API: OCR of non-language text

Tags: android, ocr, google-vision, android-vision

I'd like to write android application for text recognition in images from camera. However, text to be recognized does not consist of regular words, it's just a sequence of letters, digits, slashes, etc. Is it still possible to use Google Vision API for this task? Or should I look for some other tools? I have read about tessaract library, but Google Vision seems to be easier for beginner developer. Would it give significant boost in accuracy of recognition?

Comment: I hate to be *that guy*, but have you considered just running a bunch of your sample images through both Vision API and Tesseract? In my experience Google Vision tends toward trying to give "real" text, whereas Tesseract will just spit out whatever gibberish it finds. But really the only way to test is to run some through. You can test in the browser/command line without having to write any code.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that at least the sample OCR reader that google supplies can read non-language text strings. I have been using it to read VIN numbers, for instance.